# Analytic snippet with Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, code-snippets, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

Hopefully this is a simple question. We currently use Universal analytics but have implemented Google tag manager and setup a Universal analytics tag to fire on all pages.

Do i need to remove the Universal analytics snippet from the website? I'm assuming the tag and snippet would produce duplicate data in my analytics account.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that yes you will track twice, but without seeing the JS source you are using, it's hard to say for sure.  You can check to see if you are tracking twice by using something like Chrome developer tools and look in the network tab.  You'll see your tracking requests there and can determine if you are sending multiple or single requests on a page load.

Comment: Thanks @user3230003, i've checked and 2 tags are present:  Google Tag Manager GTM-xxxxxx and Google Analytics UA-xxxxxxxx-xx although only the UA tags says its working. I added both today so not sure if i should remove the UA tag to get the GTM working.

Comment: @Ninjasys - Install/use the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) to see if it fires multiple times. More than likely it is

Answer (score 1):

Yes, remove your hardcoded analytics snippet and use only the Google Tag manager.

to check this has all worked, goto realtime in analtyics and you should still be able to see visitors if the code is working as it should.

ALSO

Go install the chrome extension "Google Tag Assistant":
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en

That way you can see exactly what is going on with your install, if there are two instances of your tracking code it will tell you, and also flag any other errors.